# Voice Authentication Libraries for android

Tags: java, android, authentication, libraries, voice

I am making an app with needs to identify the user through his/her voice to authenticate that person.. I have searched google but it either gives me voice recognition or speech recognition tutorials.. Is it possible to perform Voice authentication in android ?

Please Advice.

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It sure sounds flashy but it would be vulnerable to the first bozo with a recording device...

Comment: Well i know that but its worth an effort ;) ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ViGo](http://voicevault.com/for-developers/) library for voice biometrics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft speaker recognition API] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/speaker-recognition-overview)

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers, and add some information here